# Entity Framework linked list

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity (I am using code first) that looks like that:

```
public class Node
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }

    public virtual Node Previous { get; set; }
    public virtual Node Next { get; set; }
}
```

There is no problem to save the Next Node for example. However if the ID of Previous is 1 and I try to set the Next Node (wich is the one with ID=1) to 2 this exception is thrown.

> The object cannot be added to the object context. The object�s
>   EntityKey has an ObjectStateEntry that indicates that the object is
>   already participating in a different relationship.

I am saving the node like this:

```
int nextId;
int previousId;
if (int.TryParse(Request["previous"], out previousId))
   node.Previous = this.nodeRepository.GetSingle(previousId);

if (int.TryParse(Request["next"], out nextId))
   node.Next = this.nodeRepository.GetSingle(nextId);

this.nodeRepository.Update(node);
```

Update looks like this:

```
public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
    this.context.Entry(GetSingle(entity.ID)).State = EntityState.Detached;
    this.context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
    this.context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

    this.Save();
}
```

And GetSingle like this:

```
public virtual T GetSingle(object id)
{
    var query = this.entities.Find(id);
    return query;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

The line with the exception is in the Update method:

```
this.context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: I believe that the problem is in the one-to-one relationship. EF only supports shared primary key associations in this case which basically means that if `Node.ID = 1` then `Node.Previous.ID` and `Node.Next.ID` must also be `1`. No other value is possible. You can only create a loop from a node to itself, so to speak. At which line exactly do you get the exception? And which values have `node.ID`, `previousId` and `nextId` when you get the exception?

Comment: Actually this does not seem to be the problem. The scenario is like this: node.id = 2; node.previous.id = 1. Now I go to node.id = 1 and try to set node.next.id = 2 - only then the exception is thrown.

Comment: Do you have any mapping with Fluent API (or data annotations)? For me the model can't be created, I get "unable to determine principal end of association" exception. Which EF version are you using?

Comment: I think the problem is with your setup of EF. If it was setup correctly then setting node[id=2].previous.id = 1 and saving changes should result in node[id=1].next.id = 2, as with EF setting only one end of relation should set the other. If your setup is correct though. Share fluent API

Comment: Show the FLUENT API mappings please. The issue will lie in how the FK relationships are defined is my guess.  The brief answer is the you should declare the FKs as MANY to MANY even though logically they  may be single relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Is your context in a Using block and being disposed of at some point?  I've had similar 'The object cannot be added to the object context." errors.  I would add Id's for Previous and Next to your model and use those to update the foreign keys.

```
public class Node
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }

    public virtual Node Previous { get; set; }
    public int PreviousId { get; set; }
    public virtual Node Next { get; set; }
    public int NextId { get; set; }
}
```

To update the foreign keys...

```
int nodeId;  // I'm assuming you know the id of node you want updated.

int nextId;
int previousId;


using (var context = new Context()) 
{     
    // Perform data access using the context 
    var node = context.Nodes.find(nodeId);
    node.NextId = nextId;
    node.PreviousId = previousId;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```